# Evaluate attribute in template function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive that uses the appropriate template based in an attribute value.
If the `tAttrs.datatype` is `input` then load an input element, if it is `select` load a select element. I have a `tmplServer` service that serves the appropriate template.

Based on an AngularJS issue (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7466), I tried to use $interpolate service, but still not working!

```
app.directive('mdmInput', ['$compile', 'tmplServer', '$timeout', '$interpolate', '$rootScope', function($compile, tmplServer, $timeout, $interpolate, $rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        value: '=',
        datatype: '@',
        finished: '&',
        valueChanged: '&',
        onDelete: '&'
    },
    template: function(tElement, tAttrs){
        return tmplServer.getTemplate($interpolate(tAttrs.datatype)(tElement.parent('.mdm-input').scope()), tAttrs);
    }
};
}]);
```

Now in the `tmplServer`:

```
getTemplate: function ( datatype, attrs ) {
    console.log(datatype);    // loges an empty string;
    if(datatype === 'select'){
        return selectTmpl;
    } else {
        return inputTmpl;
    }
}
```

In the `tmplServer.getTemplate: function ( datatype, attrs )` the `datatype` is not parsed. It is just an empty string.

Is there a way I can evaluate the attributes in the template function (before the element is attached to the DOM)?

Comment: I would check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501584/how-to-pass-in-templateurl-via-scope-variable-in-attribute

Comment: Is there no way I can do it in the template function?

Comment: I never saw it like that, always by hand pulling them via $http or $templateCache

Comment: @JesusRodriguez I don't know if $http would make a big difference. The problem is that the `tAttrs.datatype` is not evaluated (`{{data.datatype}}` instead of `text` or `select` or ...). $http would wait until the promise is returned, but when it is initiated it is still going to be '{{data.datatype}}'.

Answer (score 0):

I used AngularJS 1.3.0-beta.13 to reproduce your code.
I tested with the following html:

```
<select class="mdm-input" datatype="select"></select>
<input type="text" class="mdm-input" datatype="input"/>
```

and I get the following logs:

```
   select
   SELECT
   input
   INPUT
```

Here is what I did to get the result:

```
.directive('mdmInput', ['$compile', '$timeout', '$interpolate', '$rootScope', 'tmplServer', function($compile, $timeout, $interpolate, $rootScope, tmplServer) {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        value: '=',
        datatype: '@',
        finished: '&',
        valueChanged: '&',
        onDelete: '&'
    },

    template: function(tElement, tAttrs){
        console.log(tAttrs.datatype);
        console.log(tElement[0].nodeName);
    }
};
```

See how I get the element node name to get capitalized SELECT or INPUT, this avoid the developer to specify the datatype from the custom attribute (just in case it ease your use case).

HTH

Comment: The thing is that my directive `mdmInput` is a class of a element that I am adding in a link function of another directive. And the directive is placed on a `div` (so `tElement[0].nodeName` will be DIV) and it should render an `input` or a `select` based on the `datatype`. With your solution I am still getting `{{data.datatype}}`. I think is because when the directive is loaded the attributes on the element with the directive are not yet compiled.