# passing object from ng-repeat to templateURL attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build dynamic controls using directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="k in m.Array1" style="padding-left:30px">
     <div ng-repeat="l in k.Array2.Array3"> 
        <div control-picker var1="l" var2="k.Array2.Array3">
         </div>                        
      </div
</div>
```

The html looks like the above.

I was able to to var 1 and var 2 in the scope of directive but not into the templateURL function parameter

```
.directive('controlpicker', function () {
return {
    scope: { var1: '=', var2: '=' },
    templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
        if (scope.var1.prop1 == 'MC') {
                    return 'MultipleChoice.html';                    
            }          
            else {
                return 'Default.html';
            }
        }  }; });
```

I tried scope.var1.prop1 in all possible ways like attr.var1.prop1 but var1 turns out like a string in this case. How can I achieve it (I need to send the scope to html as well)

Comment: Check [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501584/how-to-pass-in-templateurl-via-scope-variable-in-attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get `scope` there. For dynamic templates you need to use `controller`:

```
.directive('controlpicker', function () {
return {
    template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',
    scope: { var1: '=', var2: '=' },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.getTemplateUrl = function (elem, attr) {
        if ($scope.var1.prop1 == 'MC') {
            return 'MultipleChoice.html';                    
        } else {
            return 'Default.html';
        }
      };   
    }
 });
```